# Accessing DataBinding Parameter in a PDF Form

Tags: forms, pdf, pdfbox

I have a static PDF Form created by Adobe Designer. In the properties of the text fields I can see the DataBinding value (the form is bound to an XML Schema).

[image]

I'm trying to read this information by means of Apache PDFbox 2.0 but I can get all the info but for this...

Have you any tip? 
Thank you very much
Regards 
Fabio

Comment: I assume your PDF form uses XFA (in contrast to AcroForm) form technologies?

Comment: when you create a static PDF Form using the Adobe LiveCycle Designer there are two form definitions - the AcroForm and the XFA. The AcroForm has some of the form definitions of the design being done in the Designer but not all of them. The binding information unfortunately is not part of that. What you need to do is extract the XFA and get the binding from the XFA part.

Comment: Thank you! I estracted the XFA part and I could find the mapping indeed! :-) How could I give you a 'credit'? I don't use this site very often...

Comment: @Maruan please make your comment an actual answer which Fabio can accept. Fabio: if your question is reacted to with an answer (not merely comments as currently here), you can accept that answer (by selecting the tick at its upper left) and you can upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create a static PDF Form using the Adobe LiveCycle Designer there are two form definitions - the AcroForm and the XFA. The AcroForm has some of the form definitions of the design being done in the Designer but not all of them. The binding information unfortunately is not part of that. What you need to do is extract the XFA and get the binding from the XFA part.

Comment: Hi Maruan Sahyoun. I found another answer of yours for another issue with PDFBox :-) Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874760/wrapping-an-xml-document-in-a-pdxfaresource